# Fix Warning "Also define the standard property 'box-shadow' for compatibility"

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4

I use the scroll library, and VSCode shows the following warning:

> Also define the standard property 'box-shadow' for compatibility

How can I fix it or at least ignore the warning on VSCode?

```css
.scrollbar-black::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: *"Also define the standard property 'box-shadow' for compatibility"* I don't think warning messages get any clearer than that... Add `box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);`

Comment: As Robby already mentioned. You are using only the `box-shadow` property with prefix (`-webkit`) at the moment. You should also add the `box-shadow` property without the prefix.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Or both if he wants to support older versions of webkit

Comment: Problem Solved whith `box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);` thank you

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It means you should add the standard style rule (`box-shadow`) in addition to the vendor prefixed version (`-webkit-box-shadow`)

```css
.scrollbar-black::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); // <- Add this to fix.    
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had an issue where -webkit-background-clip: text;
background-clip: hidden  was-webkit-background-text and had to match (box-shadow) and change it to background-clip then it fixed my error.