# Also define the standard property 'grid-row' for compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-code, grid, warnings

I'm getting the following warning on VS Code

> "Also define the standard property 'grid-row' for compatibility"

For this code:

```css
header {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;       /* warning here */
  -ms-grid-column: 1;    /* warning here */
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  grid-area: header;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: **See Also**: [Fix Warning "Also define the standard property 'box-shadow' for compatibility"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55586658/1366033)

Comment: Proposed duplicate does not tell how to turn off that warning if one wants to.  Also, the initial code was far more involved and confusing before the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of that, if you want, by setting this setting to `ignore`:

> CSS > Lint: Vendor Prefix
>
> ```
>   When using a vendor-specific prefix, also include the standard property.
> ```

You are getting the warnings because you use one or more of these keys

```
-ms-grid-row
-ms-grid-column
```

in your elements without also using the standard non-prefixed versions at the same time:

```
grid-row
grid-column
```

So in every element where you have `-ms-grid-row` also include, after it in the same selector, `grid-row` and the same with `-ms-grid-column` put a `grid-column` after it in the same selector.  And the warnings will go away.  This is good practice anyways.  For example:

```
header {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;   /* warning has gone away */
  grid-row: 1;

  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;

  grid-column: 2;
  grid-area: header;
}
```

Or set the `CSS > Lint: Vendor Prefix` to `ignore` and you won't see the warnings - but I do not recommend doing that.  You should be including the standard non-prefixed versions of those keys.

Comment: hi
** it's not a comment, I tried to put it a bold here for indicating where is a warning.
 for example  in the header I have a warning for these lines:
-ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
in the main section for this line :
-ms-grid-row: 2;

thanks